# Continuous integration workflow - emergency use cases

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

Let me first describe a simple CI workflow (we use git, Jenkins, maven, nexus): For a project, someone creates a branch from the master branch, makes the changes, verification and code review is done. Now someone puts a request for change.

The following is all automated.
The changes are merged to master and queued for release. To deploy, for every item in the queue, the binary is built from master branch (using a tag or commit id), run test suite, and deploy with 1% traffic. Within 12 hours, we have automatic analysis of performance numbers and business numbers, at which point we give 100% traffic. Then pick up next item in the queue.

This separation of one change per 100% release is important because it becomes really difficult to debug something wrong if multiple changes are in one release.

This would work all fine, until something breaks.

- Say we push Feature1 to 1% traffic, find the numbers to be bad, and in the 12 hours it takes to figure that out, Feature2 has been merged to master. In that case, a git revert needs to be done on Feature1, if we want Feature2 to go and revert buggy Feature1 till we fix its bugs.
- In the above case, Feature1 is very important, and we also found what is wrong and know the fix. Then we need to revert Feature2 from master, merge Feature1 fix to master and reset the queue.
- If there is some emergency fix outside of the features, and production is at Feature0 at this point, with Feature1 on pilot. We want the emergency fix on Feature0 to go 100%. This time again we need to revert Feature1 from master.

Is there a workflow, using multiple branches instead of just master or adding some more automation, which avoids git reverts - especially in cases 2 and 3 where the developer who has finished his/her feature has done nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're doing too much with master. How about a git-flow-ish model using **develop** and **release** branches, plus a separate branch for each feature and each bugfix?

Example of how it could work with the kind of scenarios you mention:

9am Production (100%) is on **release** tag 1.
Feature A is finished so branch **featureA** is merged into **develop**

10am daily rollout time ... merge **develop** into **release**, take a cut (tag 2) and roll out **release** tag 2 to 1%

11am Someone finishes coding Feature B and merges **featureB** into **develop**

12 Noon Emergency! Feature A has a bug. Roll back Production (1%) to tag 1. Take a branch from **release** tag 2 (remember **release** branch does not contain Feature B), called **bugfixA**, and start working on fixing the bug.

4pm Bug fix gets signed off - merge **bugfixA** into **release**, take a cut (tag 3) and roll. ALSO merge **bugfixA** into **develop**, and run all the tests against **develop** to make sure Bugfix A doesn't clash with Feature B.

10am next day - rollout time! Merge **develop** into **release**, take tag 4 and push to 1% - pushing Feature B that is

Meanwhile somewhere tag 3 (containing Feature A and its patch) passes the 12-hour test and moves into 100% ...

Comment: Possible issues, but I feel ok to live with:- 1) FeatureA has a bug, and FeatureB till FeatureE are merged to develop. Let FeatureF := FeatureA fix. Then next pilot has everything from FeatureB to FeatureF.
2) FeatureA just went to 1%, and we have another (independent of features) emergency to do before we have stats for FeatureA. Then FeatureA needs to be reverted from master.
3) A revert is needed when a featureX has a bug and we need to revert it since its fix has not been found and other features are waiting.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem with case (1) ... If you want to release B-E then you will need to have F with them anyway, and if you want F on its own then roll it as a bugfix. Case (2) looks like a standard bugfix case to me. Roll back production, branch off from previous tag, fix and roll, independent of features. And in case (3) revert is OK, it's what revert was made for. But in any case my answer was a suggestion of a general form, for you to tailor to your needs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have read Naomi's reply above.
This is what we are eventually working with:

Have a release branch and develop branch as described by Naomi. The only difference here is that we allow merges to release at any point between release HEAD (which is behind develop) and develop HEAD. This allows us to limit number of features being released as well as unblocking devs to merge their new features from a feature branch to develop branch as soon as they are done.

In addition to this, we added a seperate "hotfix" branch. This will generally remain much behind of the release branch, and used only when required. Let's say a feature X is rolled out 1%, and we need to roll out an emergency fix to 100% independent of feature X. Then we update hotfix branch to the point where we are at 100% (behind feature X), make changes there, and build/test/release from the hotfix branch itself. After this, we need to merge this fix to master and develop for future releases.

This minimizes the revert cases for us.